# NSMutableArray's objects are same

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *backprop;
NSMutableArray *backlist;

[backprop setValue:self.val forKey:@"id"];//NSLog for self.val
[backprop setValue:title.text forKey:@"name"];//NSLog for title.text
[backlist insertObject:backprop atIndex:backlist.count];
```

Here I add `backprops` to `backlist`. I add `NSLogs` different values. Thats what I want.
But when I log them with this code:

```
while (i!=backlist.count) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",[[backlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id" ],[[backlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name" ]);i++;
    }
```

They all same with the last object. Why is this like that? Thank you.

Comment: perhaps that's happening because you actually log the last object instead of using the `i` variable for indexes -_-

Comment: Actually you'r right, my fault but didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
I define NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary under @implementation in .m file..
I had to empty backprop.

So I changed my code:

```
-(void)....{
NSMutableDictionary *backprop = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [backprop setObject:self.val forKey:@"id"];
  [backprop setObject:title.text forKey:@"name"];

  [backlist addObject:backprop];NSInteger i=0;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are using backlist.count-1 as your index instead of using i.

try this:

```
while (i!=backlist.count) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",[[backlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id" ],[[backlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name" ]);i++;
    }
```